# What means :: on the front of a function call

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
1. bool MyClass::open() {
2.   int fd = ::open("file.txt",flags);
3. }
```

Does the "::" from the line 2 before calling open means something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means "`open` from the global namespace". It is a way to disambiguate with `MyClass::open`, which is a name that would be picked up if you said `open` without the leading `::`.

Answer (score 4):

It's *scope resolution operator* and it says, that the function (`open` in this case) is in the *global namespace*.